# Xcode 9, Selected code snippet type removed when enter key is pressed

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

In XCode 8.3.3 and below when a code snippet was highlighted and you hit enter, XCode would replace the snippet type with the actual type.

Now when you hit enter it deletes the placeholder type. I've looked around in preferences and cannot find a setting to revert this.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to Xcode 10 and it solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Shift + Enter should leave the highlighted text in place